# Finitely presented group with exactly two conjugacy classes

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a finitely presented group with exactly two conjugacy classes other than $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: This is a famous open question.

Comment: @HJRW is there a published reference identifying it as such? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: See FP18 here: http://shpilrain.ccny.cuny.edu/gworld/problems/probFP.html. It asks whether there's an infinite f.p. group with finitely many conjugacy classes. Published reference: *G.Baumslag, A.G.Myasnikov and V.Shpilrain, Open problems  in combinatorial group theory. Second edition, Contemp. Math., Amer. Math. Soc. 296 (2002), 1-38*. [link at Shpilrain's page](http://shpilrain.ccny.cuny.edu/problems2.pdf).